# Having trouble earning the 'Fanatic' badge - something's up with the time...

Tags: discussion, badges

For quite a while now, I've been trying to earn the 'Fanatic' badge. According to the description, I have to "visit the site for 100 consecutive days." Easy enough. I'm on every day barring emergencies or minor natural disasters.

I've gotten close (up to 79 at one point I think), but it's always reset before I can reach 100. Some of these are me not logging on, sure. But it seems to me that an awful lot of these resets don't make sense.

The SE day is measured in UTC, which ends at 5 PM PST, which is where I am. I never close the tab with Writers SE open on it. I visit and refresh it every morning (about 7-9 AM PST), throughout the day, and the last thing at night (about 11 PM PST). I did this yesterday, but somehow it counted me as not visiting the site all day long. There was a three hour block of time I was not active on the site from 5 PM to 8 PM, but I was on directly before and directly after.

So either something weird is going on with the time, or there's a requirement that I don't know about. Could anyone help me figure out what is happening?

Note: With every single reset, there is a block of time where I've left the computer for a few hours, like yesterday. However, these blocks of time are nowhere near enough to count as an entire day, and I always come on directly before and after each block. So either I'm missing a hidden three hour day the system is counting, or....

Answer (score 4):

Are you visiting some page on the site, other than the front page, every day?  Just visiting the main URL is, as far as I know, not enough to count; you need to actually read a question or something.

Good luck in your pursuit of fanaticism!  Sorry to hear you've gotten bounced along the way, but I hope our site is attractive enough that you can find something worth reading every day. :-)

Comment: Ohhhh... that could be it. I'll have to investigate. It seems I've just refreshed the main page plenty of days and it didn't bounce me, but I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks!